# One of the SpringBoot RestController stops working after few days

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, performance, spring-mvc

We have a RestController in spring boot that connects to another endpoint and pulls around 7000 to 8000 records. This API works fine for few days after that whenever we hit the endpoint we get a 500 error. And there is nothing in the logs, except the below message. There is no stack trace also. When we hit the endpoint at that time it does not even invoke the method. We are not sure how to approach this problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
[http-nio-8081-exec-81] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException] with root cause
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
```

Comment: Enable debug logging and see what happens before/after this happens.

Comment: it's hard to tell just by looking into that indexOutOfBound exception, what happens in those "few days"? is there any change on the server-side like network, maybe looking into server/container/proxy logs would give you more details than just the application logs

Comment: @Deinum any specific class or package  you want to enable logs on, there is no change on server side, users just uses the API.

Comment: I would start with the web stuff, as you state it doesn't invoke the controller method at all it breaks before that.